Как запустить файл python (file.py) на хостинге? Может php кодом это как-то можно сделать?
Есть хостинг. На основном сайте создал поддомен тип (pd.site.com)
На этом поддомене установил и активировал виртуальное окружение для python.
Разместил там простенький стартовый файл run.py (простенький телеграм бот)
Из виртуального окружения запускаю файл

python run.py

бот работает, но естественно хостинг не позволяет работать скрипту в режиме ожидания. Процесс сбрасывается хостингом через некоторое время.
Я так понимаю нужен php файл, который связан вэбхуком с ботом может запустить run.py
Есть ли такая возможность? И как выглядит скрипт, который способен запустить run.py?
Прилагаю картинку файлов на сайте, может она поможет получить правильный ответ.
Файл bt.php это тот файл, который должен бы запустить run.py
index.php пустой


Я предполагаю, что под "но естественно хостинг не позволяет работать скрипту в режиме ожидания" вы имеете ввиду, что если запустить run.py и разорвать SSH соединение, то процесс run.py падает. Это нормально, иначе было бы сложно уследить за всеми процессами запущенными через SSH.
Если вы хотите чтобы run.py работал в фоновом режиме можно запустить его через утилиту screen (просто и быстро) или создать сервис для systemd чтобы линукс сам запускал бота, точно так же как он, например, запускает sshd, который отвечает за SSH подключения (сложно, но надёжно).
Запуск через утилиту screen:

Устанавливаем утилиту
apt install screen


Создаём сессию session_name где потом будет запущен run.py
screen -S session_name


Находясь внутри сессии запускаем файл
cd /path/to/folder
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
python run.py


Теперь процесс будет работать в сессии session_name даже если вы отключитесь от SSH. Если вы не хотите отключаться от SSH, то можно отсоединиться от сессии нажав CTRL+A+D
Если нужно обратно присоединится к сессии session_name можно использовать команду
screen -x session_name



Утилита screen, как по мне, один из самых простых способов запускать что-то на фоне, для образовательных целей. Но никогда не используйте её для production продукта.

Не совсем всё верно поняли. Я не рзрываю соединение.  Хостинг расположен на https://adm.tools/

Там же предоставляют терминал SSH. Я запускаю run.py через терминал.  Вечером, не разрывая соединение, закрываю окно, выключаю комп - бот работает.  Утром бот уже не работает. Возвращаюсь в терминал, он запускаетяся, но активных процессов нет. Значит хостер закрыл это соединение. И бота я хочу запустить не только в образовательных целях, а в образовательно-практических. У меня есть группа 1Т чел. Там бот работает с компа (PyCharm)/ Собирает данные, удаляет спам. Поэтому хочу чтоб работал суточно

Поэтому  для начала хочу понять как возможно командой с php запустить run.py

А за утилиту screen спасибо. Запустил в фоновом режиме, вроде работает. Посмотрим закроет хостер сессию или нет.

И должен уточнить. Сайт у меня на обычном хостинге (не VPS)

@АлексейРыженко для меня обычный хостинг это VPS/VDS. Такому хостингу неестественно сбрасывать процессы по своей воле. Так что я не совсем понимаю что именно у вас за проблема. Если всё ещё интересно запускать python код через php, то могу предложить просто запускать его консольной командой: system("source /path/to/venv/bin/activate && python /path/to/run.py");

Запустил в фоновой сессии. Работает несколько дней, не закрывает сессию.  Обчный хостинг я называю для сайта, а VPS это персональный сервер, где можно устанавить всё необходимое, что обычный хостинг может не дать. Так было ранее с сайтом. Хостер не предоставлял Python (предлагали купить VPS/VDS) для обычного хостинга, но со временем они дали доступ и к Python.  Но думаю возможности ограничены в сравнении VPS. Хотя для простых ботов для себя возможно подойдёт. Ведь зачем платить за VPS, если больше половины выделенного пустует. Попробую ещё Ваш совет консольной командой
